# How to set mongo.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How to Set mongo.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier in Jmeter. I am using Mongo Source Config and want to increase this. How can i do this on Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it in "`Block Multiplier`" in `MongoDB Source Config`

[image]